# JNI Error in Apache POI libraries

Tags: java, cmd, javac

So i'm currently attempting to execute a Java program from the command line in Windows.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*; 
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
```

In the command line I have accounted for multiple libraries, with Apache (3.17) coming up with errors. I have checked the build path, and all the external libraries are compiled in the command line with no issues

```
cd C:\Users\Joshuab\Desktop\ATS\workExcelApplication\src
set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin
javac -cp C:\Users\Joshuab\Desktop\ATS\ATS\API\poi-3.17\/* Check.java
java Check
```

At `java Check` in the Command line I get the error

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and
try again Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/apache/poi/ss/use rmodel/Row
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
```

I've looked around for a solution finding others with similar issues, but no solution. So I then the questions are:

1. what/where is the problem.
2. How can I resolve it
3. if there is a solution or documentation could you send a link or anything related.

Comment: You should get Apache POI libraries(JAR), as `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row` belongs to the same library, and add the same in your project.

Comment: Why have you got `\/*` at the end of your classpath?

Comment: it tells it to get all the .jar files in the path

Comment: This is not 'in the `javac` libraries. It is in the *Apache POI* libraries. And Java is not a scripting language, and this is not a script. Be accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

```
cd C:\Users\Joshuab\Desktop\ATS\workExcelApplication\src
set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin
java -cp ".\*;" Check
```

it took a while to figure out and to help anyone else if they have an issue similar to this. I found the solution in the javac documentation which you can find here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html

So when the using the interpreter you need to specify the API's and other external libraries, with ".\ *;" being the current directory with all external libraries.